# Is this a representation of Dirac delta?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, dirac-delta

I have read that

$$ \lim_{\substack{t \to \infty \\ \eta \to 0 \\ \eta t \to 0}} \frac{e^{-i x_0 t}}{x_0 - x +i\eta} = -2\pi i \delta (x - x_0) $$

where $\delta$ is Dirac delta and the limit is meant in [this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function). Is this true? How do I prove it? How do I get the prefactor $-2 \pi i$?

Comment: where did you find this ? it doesn't look correct to me

Comment: @user1952009 In one of my proffesor's notes. Intuitively, though, it makes sense because the fraction tends to zero unless $x_0 - x = 0$. It just doesn't say anything about the prefactor...

Comment: now the Fourier transform of $\frac{e^{1+i x n}}{x-i / n}$ should be  $2i \pi \, Res(\frac{e^{1+i x n-2i \pi \xi x}}{x-i / n},i/n) =  2i \pi e^{2 \pi \xi / n}$ so it $\to 2i \pi$ as $n \to \infty$, and hence (if $\widehat{\varphi}$ is compactly supported) $\langle \frac{e^{1+i x n}}{x-i / n},\varphi \rangle =\langle 2i \pi e^{2 \pi \xi / n},\widehat{\varphi} \rangle \to \langle 2i \pi, \widehat{\varphi} \rangle  = \langle 2i \pi\delta, \varphi \rangle$. Is it what you meant ?

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks, this definitely helps! Only in the context of the problem it was said that we can assume $\eta t \to 0$ (instead of $\eta t = 1$ like you did), which I will add to the post. So we can have $e^{ixt}$ in the numerator instead of $e^{1+ixt}$.